# Displaystyle equations in a tabular

Tags: tables, equations

I'm trying to write a table with fixed width and equations in displaystyle. I wrote

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{6cm}|p{6cm}|} 
\hline
stuff1 & stuff2\\
\hline
\pbox{6cm}{some text
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
a+b=c \\
d+e=f
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
} 
& \pbox{6cm}{some text
\begin{equation}
a+b=c
\end{equation}
text.
} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\\
\end{center}
```

I get an error saying

> Missing $ inserted.

I tried to change the equation command many different times but i sitll get an error.

Comment: just remove the pbox command which is non standard and the cause of the error, assuming it is from the package of that name, you do not say.

Comment: That was it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show a full example or a definition of `\pbox` but the table works as expected if you remove that.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\addtolength\textwidth{30pt}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{6cm}|p{6cm}|} 
\hline
stuff1 & stuff2\\
\hline
some text
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
a+b=c \\
d+e=f
\end{gathered}
\end{equation} 
& 
some text
\begin{equation}
a+b=c
\end{equation}
text.
 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}  
\end{center}

\end{document}
```